# Using root in fedora 20?

Tags: sudo, fedora-20

I want to be able to run commands as root... How do i do this?

`sudo yum install @kde-desktop`
`cromwell is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.`

I found a post saying to edit `/etc/pam.d/gdm` but there are several variants (`gdm-password`, `gdm-pin`, etc) and i dont really want to go out on a limb.

This is the first question i have, with my first time running Fedora  I am very pleased that it comes with the up to date software i am looking for. Any and all help getting past this simple problem would be greatly appreciated.

**How do i make the `sudo` command work in fedora 20? (I do not want to log in as root, simply run the commands as root)**

**EDIT**
the following is a copy-paste from my bash prompt:

```
[root@localhost /]# sudo adduser cromwell sudo  
Usage: adduser [options] LOGIN  
       adduser -D  
       adduser -D [options]  

Options:  
  -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory of the  
.............  
  -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     use a specific SEUSER for the SELinux user mapping  

[root@localhost /]#
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried the following command, as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user):

`sudo usermod -aG sudo cromwell`

it then says: `group 'sudo' does not exist`

i then enter `sudo usermod -aG` and press tab a few times...

output

> abrt                 chrony               ftp                  halt
>   nobody               root                 tss adm
>   colord               games                lp                   openvpn
>   rtkit                unbound avahi                cromwell
>   gdm                  mail                 operator
>   shutdown             usbmuxd avahi-autoipd        daemon
>   geoclue              mysql                polkitd              sshd
>   bin                  dbus                 gnome-initial-setup 
>   nm-openconnect       pulse                sync

i then ran the following command `sudo usermod -aG adm cromwell` and it ran with no error... i did a full reboot, and once logged back in i ran `sudo mkdir`~/test`... then low and behold i get the same error about the sudoers list =(

(it may be worth noting that i did manage to install kde by logging in as root, therefore i am currently using KDE as my desktop. but still.... how do i use sudo?)

***EDIT* SHOULD I ADD MY USER TO THE `root` GROUP?**
(EDIT- i am told here to NOT do this, as it will result in massive security issues)

**EDIT**

the first option of the accepted answer was what worked. THE SECOND OPTION DID NOT. This should be noted here, or the second option deleted

=========================================
Note, if this is off topic for super user (or not within the expertise of this website) please let me know, and i will personally flag it for migration. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sudo's configuration file is /etc/sudoers.  You can't modify this directly, even as root, so instead you must use the command `visudo` to pull up an editor.  Of course,you'll have to have elevated privileges to run visudo, so use the `su` command first.

In this file, you can assign sudo permissions to users and/or groups, and do many other things besides :)

In your case, add the following line to the sudoers file, opened via visudo:

`cromwell ALL=(ALL) ALL`

This will enable cromwell to do anything by using the sudo command.

Fedora's default editor is vim, which can confuse users who aren't familiar with it.  First, press `i` for Insert.  The word "Insert" will appear at the bottom of the screen.  Now you can make your changes.  To save them, first press `ESC` to go back to Command Mode.  Then, type `:wq`  This Writes the file, then Quits the editor.

---

Other notes:

In Debian-based distributions, there is a sudo group set up by default, and this group is referenced in sudoers as `%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL`.  (The percentage sign a signifies a group). You could do this too, by choosing (or creating) an appropriate group, and adding it to sudoers.

Once this is done, you can simply add a user to that group.  Without root access, however, you won't be able to.

So, to get root access:

`su`

Then, to add the user to the sudo group (for example):

`adduser cromwell sudo`

Then, you'll have to logout and log back in for sudo to work.

Good luck!

Comment: after using the above command, it provided usage documentation. I logged out and back in. It still gives the same warning when attempting to use the `sudo` command as the user `cromwell`. Are you 100% positive that this is the correct format for the command? The usage says `adduser [option] login`... this says it would be `adduser sudo cromwell`, but i dont want to add sudo to the group cromwell by misunderstanding the usage page. Thoughts? ---EDIT: Rebooting to see if it helps

Comment: no dice =( I dont get it... Other resources say to do this very same thing. I can use `su` to log in as root, and successfully run the following command `sudo mkdir /home/cromwell/sudo-test` but all adduser gives me is a usage page, and apparently doesnt do what its supposed to...

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen I added to my answer. I hope it helps!

Comment: i dont have a sudo group in fedora 20... so i used adm (which should have su privilages) still nothing... see the second edit on the question

Comment: should i add my user to the `root` group?

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen There, I gave another update.  Hopefully this works!  No, you don't want to be a root member, it makes the system susceptible to errors and exploits...

Comment: The first option worked, thank you =) (i did have trouble figuring out the difference between insert and command mode)

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen Excellent!  Glad it's working.  As far as insert and command modes, it sounds like your default text editor is vi or vim.  They're powerful and old-school, and pretty arcane at times :)  There are different editors, if you prefer.  If you search for editor recommendations, prepare for heated discussion! Take care.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the root/administrator details (the one used during setup) then try [to configure sudo](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Configuring_Sudo).  I've used usermod before and it worked I did have the root user to do it obviously.